# How to do Ajax search in code igniter using api call?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to create an ajax search for code igniter using the api call.

The scenario is:

I have a textbox in which if i will type some thing ,it will call the api function  written in the controller.There is no db calls.

**View**

```
<input type="text" id="channel_name"  value="" name="channel_name" class="form-control valid">
<div id="channel_details">result will be here</div>
```

**I used jquery auto complete js The js code i written:**

```
 var $ha = jQuery.noConflict();
 $ha(document).ready(function(){ 
    $ha('#channel_name').blur(function(){ 
        $ha.get('/search/fetch',{channel:$ha("#channel_name").val()},
        function(data){ 
            $ha('#channel_details').val(data); 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

---

**In the controller:**

```
public function fetch() { 
    $value1=$this->input->get('channel'); 
    $this->load->library('swsdk'); 
    $data = $this->swsdk->searchBroadcast($this->input->get('channel')); 
    echo json_encode($data->content); 
    return $value1; 
}
```

---

But it is not working or it is not the proper way to do a call.

Could you please suggest a working code for this?

Comment: where you getting `$this->input->get('name')`, `page`, `size` in `fetch()` method?

Comment: @RazibAlMamun update my question

Comment: try to remove `return $value1;` in `fetch()` method

Comment: First, remove `.val()` from `$ha('#channel_details').val(data); ` because `div` doesn't have any value.. Use  `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery. After done ajax request use `.html(data)` not `.val(data)` like `$('#channel_details').html(data);`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#channel_name').blur(function(){
        var channel = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            url: base_url+'/search/fetch',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {channel:channel},
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#channel_details').html(data);
        }).fail(function (data) {
            console.log('failed');
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Removed `return $value1;` this line in `fetch()` method from your controller like bellow :

```
public function fetch() { 
    $value1=$this->input->get('channel'); 
    $this->load->library('swsdk'); 
    $data = $this->swsdk->searchBroadcast($this->input->get('channel')); 
    echo json_encode($data->content); 
    //return $value1; 
}
```